# Windows Wont boot up after clearing CMOS

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, cmos

I cleared my cmos and windows cant boot up. it says `inaccessible_boot_device`
how can i fix this? btw im using a ssd for windows and a hdd for other stuff

Comment: are your SATA buses configured for AHCI or ATA? what happens if you switch it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What mode was your hard drive controller in when you installed Windows?

ATA / AHCI / RAID ?

Resetting your CMOS probably changed it.  You need to access your CMOS setup program and change it back to what it was when Windows was installed.

[Microsoft says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559218%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE bug check frequently occurs because of a
>   boot device failure. During I/O system initialization, the boot device
>   driver might have failed to initialize the boot device (typically a
>   hard disk).

Comment: i removed my hdd sata cable to another slot and it got fixed. also i changed it to RAID mode again thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

This may be issue with the current boot feature that is in use. If your motherboard supports both EFI and secure boot, you may need to enable legacy boot mode and disable secure boot to load Windows.

If the above fails you can try rebooting once again in secure boot. Checking your IDE settings can also help resolve the issue. Make sure to trouble shoot and test  IDE or AHCI which would cause a conflict.

You may be using IDE when it has been running on AHCI.

Another method:

```
Take out all of your ram except for 1 stick, leave in the 1 stick thats 
closest to your cpu.

 Then reboot, with only 1 stick of ram in your PC, this will allow you to 
 get past the post screen, and enter your bios.

Once in your bios, make sure your memory settings are correct!

Check the MHz (speed/frequency)
 your timings
 your voltage

 I've had this exact same problem, after clearing the Cmos, it just wacked 

 out the memory settings.
 So you need to use ONLY 1 stick of ram to get back in!

 Once you've checked all of your bios settings, shut down, replace the rest 
 of your ram, and reboot to windows.
```

You can try a shorter method and try the following:

> Remove all components except CPU and RAM, reset CMOS again and try to boot.

Comment: i tried removing ram but it didnt had an effect. but i removed the hdd and it worked! thanks so much.